# ExtJS 4 Arrow Navigation for Tab Panel

Tags: extjs4, keyevent, extjs-mvc, tabpanel

I'm trying to make the tabs in tabpanel navigable using arrow keys.

As tabpanel has no key events, my guess was to create a KeyMap or 
a KeyNav and attach it to the panel this way: 
This is part of the tabpanel def, it's inside another panel:

```
activeTab : 0,
xtype : 'tabpanel',
id : 'tabPanel',
alias : 'widget.mainpanels',    
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(tb) {
        this.bindDetailsPanelKeys(tb);
    },
    scope: this
}, [...]
```

And the function bindDetailsPanelKeys:

```
bindDetailsPanelKeys: function(tb) {
    console.log(tb); //Checking tb is the correct object.
    var tbMap = new Ext.util.KeyMap(tb, {           
    key: Ext.EventObject.RIGHT,
    fn: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    // Code to calculate next tab and switch it.
    }
});
```

console.log(tb) output is as expected, it contains the tab panel object.

But all I receive after that is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of null` from line `var tbMap = new Ext.util.KeyMap(tb, {`

I've checked the El property of tb and it's also correct and it has the on method on it's proto as well.

Any help will be very appreciated.

**EDIT: I've found the solution. I'll post it in a moment.**

Agustin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is how I managed to get around it.

In first place I defined the tabpanel with its tabbar and as follows:

```
[...]
activeTab : 0,
xtype : 'tabpanel',
id : 'tabPanel',
alias : 'widget.mainpanels',
tabBar: {
    id: 'tabPanelTabBar',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(tb, eOpts) {
        this.bindDetailsPanelKeys(tb);
    },
    scope: this
}},[...]
```

For each tab item I added an attribute 'index' as I'didn't find another way to get
the current tab numerical position. Here's an example:

```
{
    xtype : 'categoryEdit',
    title : 'Detalles Categoría',                                   
    index: 1
}
```

And the binding function as follows. As [Saket Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237812/saket-patel) suggested I'm giving the KeyMap constructor a reference to the 'el' element of the tab-bar (notice it's TabBar's 'el', **not** TabPanel's 'el').

```
bindDetailsPanelKeys: function(tabBar) {
    var tbRightMap = new Ext.util.KeyMap(tabBar.getEl(), { //RIGHT ARROW
        key: Ext.EventObject.RIGHT,
        fn: function(e) {
            var totalItems = tabBar.items.length, //total tabs
            activeTabIndex = tabBar.tabPanel.getActiveTab().index, //current tab index
            nextTabIndex = (activeTabIndex % totalItems) + Math.ceil(activeTabIndex/totalItems) - 1; //Calculate next index    
            tabBar.tabPanel.setActiveTab(nextTabIndex);
        }
});

var tbLeftMap = new Ext.util.KeyMap(tabBar.getEl(), { //LEFT ARROW          
    key: Ext.EventObject.LEFT,
    fn: function(e) {
        var totalItems = tabBar.items.length,
        activeTabIndex = tabBar.tabPanel.getActiveTab().index;
        prevTabIndex = (activeTabIndex == 1) ? 3 : activeTabIndex - 2;
        tabBar.tabPanel.setActiveTab(prevTabIndex);
}
});
```

I hope somebody finds it useful.

Answer (score 1):

according to documentation the `Ext.util.KeyMap` object expects a html element or Ext.Element object, so `instead of passing tabpanel object you need to pass element of the tabpanel`, so you can do something like this and check if its working or not

```
var tbMap = new Ext.util.KeyMap(tb.getEl(), {           
     key: Ext.EventObject.RIGHT,
     fn: function(e) {
          console.log(e);
          // Code to calculate next tab and switch it.
     }
});
```

Comment: Already tried that. The error dissapears but the event is never fired.
Anyway, I didn't notice about the fact that KeyMap expects that, so I'll investigate on that. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no reputation to thank you, I would do it otherwise.

Comment: you don't need reputation to uptick answers

Comment: It says I need 15 of reputation to do it.